# How to convert String to datetime problem

Tags: c#

Converting to datetime hasn't worked with everything i have tried

This is what I have tried, I have date saved in sql datebase and the column is set to "text" I know my mistake next time I will set it to date time but since I have it in text, when I retrieve the data and try to convert to datetime it does work.

I keep getting this error "String not in datetime format" I have tried so may options that I have commented out but still get same errors, any help.

```
DateTime gottenoldexpiringdate = new DateTime();

string expiringdatedds = "";
conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connString;
conn.Open();

string querysasds = "Select * from paymentrecord Where deleted='No' and membersecretid='" + membersecretid + "' order by id desc limit 1";
MySqlCommand cmasddaa = new MySqlCommand(querysasds, conn);
MySqlDataReader dataReaderxxasdf = cmasddaa.ExecuteReader();
dataReaderxxasdf.Read();

if (dataReaderxxasdf.HasRows)
{
         
    string gotttenoldexp = dataReaderxxasdf["expiringdate"] + "";
    expiringdatedds = dataReaderxxasdf["expiringdate"] + "";
    conn.Close();
    //to int first

    gotttenoldexp = gotttenoldexp.Replace("/", "");

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(gotttenoldexp));

    //MessageBox.Show(gotttenoldexp.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
    int tointgotttenoldexp = Convert.ToInt32(gotttenoldexp);

    MessageBox.Show( Convert.ToString(tointgotttenoldexp));

    DateTime dateInString = new DateTime();
    dateInString = Convert.ToDateTime(tointgotttenoldexp);
    string expiringdate = Convert.ToString(dateInString.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(30)));
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(expiringdate);
    string expiringdated = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(expiringdated));
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example string that might be stored in this text field? Hard to tell why it won't convert without seeing what it is.

Comment: @JohnWu 12/06/2023

Comment: @BluevelsTechnology Is that June 12 or December 6?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen June 12, but i want it in such a way i can convert it to any date format I want.

Comment: Suggested reading: [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Can you explain why you are converting the field to an `int` before attempting to convert it to a `DateTime`?

Comment: @JohnWu because I tried converting from string to datetime it did work so i tried using int to see if that will work, also didnt work

Comment: If you have a string that contains a date in the current system format then `Convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.Parse` will do the job. If the format is specific and may not be the system format then `DateTime.ParseExact` will do the job. If the data may not be valid then `TryParse` or `TryParseExact` is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

To read a database field as a string, you'd use something like this:

```
string gotttenoldexp = dataReaderxxasdf["expiringdate"] as string;
```

The reason I am using `as string` is there is a chance the field is `DbNull`. A cast would fail. Using `as` checks the type and converts the field to a string if it is present.

Once you have the string, I recommend you print it out to make sure it is what you were expecting.

To convert to a date/time, you'd use

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(gotttenoldexp);
```

Or if you know the field is in an exact format you can use

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(gotttenoldexp, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Or if you're not sure, or to support more than one format:

```
var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
var ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(gotttenoldexp, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result);
if (!ok) throw new Exception("I don't know that format.");
```

Once again, I recommend you print the value or look at it in the debugger to make sure it is what you expect.

To output the datetime in a specific format, use an overload of `ToString()`.

```
MessageBox.Show(gotttenoldexp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```